# Analytics oriented database

Tags: performance, databases

I'm analyzing a single large table (about 50GB 16M rows, 15 columns perhaps more) currently using PostgreSQL 9.4.
Most of my queries doesn't involve more tables.

Queries run time are very large. I'm comparing it to similar queries in Tableau.
I know this comparison is not fair, Tableau extract was designed for this usage.
Nevertheless i think that i'm not the only one looking for such a solution.

What i'm looking for is:

1. Database (probably relational)
2. Analytics oriented (no updates\deletes are required)
3. Fast (like using a tableau extract)
4. Supports SQL queries
5. Preferably open-source
6. Will not require much optimization (i don't want to be responsible for indexes creation, like in Tableau extract creation)

To illustrate: if i had the ability to connect to a Tableau extract locally like to a localhost database and run SQL quires on it, this will be great.

Comment: I think you're looking for a columnar database. look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_column-oriented_DBMSes) wikipedia page for a list.

Comment: Can't you just install 64GB of RAM and push your table there?

Comment: Let's say i'm willing to install 64GB RAM, i'm looking for a DB\Soloution that will allow to easly "push" the table there. Currently i'm trying Oracle's "in_memory" option following @phiver's comment.